# I need to count those that are not selected

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I have a access 2003 table of employees. There are two columns. First one is the site name and second column is the status. By the following query string I can easily count those that has the status of "Completed"

```
SELECT employee.[Site Name], Count(employee.EID) AS [Number of Completed]
FROM employee
WHERE (((employee.[status])="Completed"))
GROUP BY employee.[Site Name]
```

The question is:
There are some sites that are not in the list, those sites that no employee has "Completed" status. I need to list them as well but with the value 0.
Any solution in Access 2003 helps me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do conditional aggregation.  In MS Access, this looks like:

```
SELECT employee.[Site Name],
       SUM(IIF(employee.[status] = "Completed", 1, 0)) AS [Number of Completed]
FROM employee
GROUP BY employee.[Site Name];
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you. I should add that the user can combine conditions by AND and OR inside the first part of the IIF statement.